# Write a regex that recognizes dogs and cats that are big or fluffy. (from learning program)

Tags: regex

The program asks me to "Write a regex that recognizes dogs and cats that are big or fluffy."
The closest I've come is this:

```
var re = /^big|fluffy dog$/
```

This was my result:
[image: test results]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?:big|fluffy)\s+(?:dog|cat)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zAQaVS/1/). With an `i` flag, as in the demo, you may make the pattern case insensitive.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string anchor
- `(?:big|fluffy)` - a non-capturing group matching `big` or `fluffy`
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces (remove `+` to match just one)
- `(?:dog|cat)` - a non-capturing group matching `dog` or `cat`
- `$` - end of string.